# Breaking bundled products in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I had a simple query to calculate average quantity of products sold in last 3 days. Now I have to extend query so that it decouples bundled products.

### Database structure (simplified):

**order**

- id
- date_order_created_at

**order_product**

- product_sku
- quantity
- order_id

**product_bundle**

- product_sku - "child" product_sku
- bundle_sku - "parent/bundle" product_sku
- quantity - represents quantity of products included in bundle

**product**

- product_sku
- name

### Example data

For an example, `order_product` might contain a bundle item "Hand cream + body cream", which would have to be displayed as 2 items, this should be achievable using `product_bundle` table.

Before there was requirement for displaying quantity of products sold in bundles, I was able to use following query to display average quantity of sold items in last 3 days:

```sql
SELECT p.name 
     , SUM(op.quantity)/3 avg_3_days
  FROM order_product op
  LEFT 
  JOIN `order` o 
    ON o.id = op.order_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN product p
    ON p.sku = op.product_sku 
 WHERE o.date_order_created_at BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)))
 GROUP 
    BY p.name
 ORDER 
    BY avg_3_days DESC
```

Now I would like to break bundles apart using data from `product_bundle` and display them as a singular products including with all the non-bundle products. Product bundle may contain 2 or more items.

I already tried with various UNION and sub query statements but I just can't get my head around it. 
Would this even be possible to achieve using current database structure?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I prefer to avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers; it's a little easier on the eyes!

Comment: True, specially with 'order'. Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of failed attempts I succeed using combination of an UNION and LEFT JOIN statements.

```
SELECT 
    op.product_sku,
    SUM(op.quantity) / 3 AS `avgLast3days`
FROM
    order_product op
        LEFT JOIN
    `order` o ON o.id = op.order_id
WHERE
    o.date_order_created_at > '2020-05-17'
        AND op.product_sku NOT IN (SELECT 
            bundle_sku
        FROM
            product_bundle)
GROUP BY op.product_sku 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    pb.product_sku,
    SUM(pb.quantity * op.quantity) / 3 AS `avgLast3days`
FROM
    product_bundle pb
        LEFT JOIN
    order_product op ON op.product_sku = pb.bundle_sku
        LEFT JOIN
    `order` o  ON o.id = op.order_id
WHERE
    o.date_order_created_at > '2020-05-17'
GROUP BY pb.product_sku
ORDER BY avgLast3days DESC
```